# Zend OpenID with PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, openid

I'm using the Zend OpenID library found [here](https://github.com/marcinwol/zfopenid). I see there is a demo up, which works beautifully, but I don't see any source included for login.php. When I bring the files into my local apache and try to replicate what I see by viewing the source in the demo, I see an interface. When trying to use one of the login options, I see it makes posts like

```
http://localhost/zfopenid/public/user/login?action=verify&openid_username=&openid_identifier=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.aol.com%2F
```

so there is certainly some php involved in that login file that I'm not able to see. I tried including application/controllers/UserController.php, but I get

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Controller_Action' not found in /var/www/zfopenid/application/controllers/UserController.php on line 3
```

Comment: Do you have a working Zend Framework installed and trying to include into your ZF project? Or just a stand alone approach?

Comment: yes, make sure that you have ZF installed in your PHP include_path (or add it to your include path.

Comment: I downloaded the .tar.gz off the github and extracted it to the root of my web directory. I believe it has the ZF included in 'library/Zend' In my 'public/user/login.php', I have

'require_once('../../application/controllers/UserController.php');'

Comment: Just a note: If you don't want to use the Zend Framework, Janrain has an OpenID library: (I personally use a semi-custom build of this): http://www.janrain.com/openid-enabled.  Also, here is a resource about how to build an OpenID system with such a library: http://www.plaxo.com/api/openid_recipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know this Zend OpenID library but it sounds interesting. The problem is, at first look, it is tightly integrated into the Zend Framework and not a stand alone library. You'll have to run it as ZF application or find the components and then try if you can use them.

**UPDATE** If you want to test the downloaded application you have to make the `/public` directory your web root directory and the `index.php` your default root file. Then you can open the demo yourself. Again if you like to integrate it into your project it will be difficult because for what I see so far there is code all over the place which makes it increasingly difficult if you want it as a stand alone application.